# Estimating the derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the following equation: 
$$
u = \frac{x^a + x^b}{y^a + y^b}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $u,x,y$ are variables, I want to estimate the derivatives $dx/du$ or $dy/du$. However I cannot obtain the closed-form $x$ as a function of $u$ and $y$ (or $y$ as a function of $u$ and $x$). So my question is are there any methods to estimate $dx/du$ or $dy/du$ (in closed form)?

Comment: Some thoughts for you.  The "typical" way to estimate derivatives is with differences.  Alternatively, you can replace your function u with something that well approximates it but is easier to differentiate.  For example the Stone-Weierstrass theorem offers you approximating polynomials, and I believe they approximate the derivatives as well (at least that is true in one dimension).  As another example you could replace u piecewise with splines of various degrees -- this is a common way to approximate disagreeable functions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will follow that direction to see hows it going.

Comment: @widapol: Are $x$ and $y$ connected to each other or they are independent. I mean $y=f(x)$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are not independent.

Comment: @widapol as B.S. points out the independence or not of x and y matters a lot.  I guess I was just assuming independence.  If they are dependent -- y = f(x) you can, theoretically, use the 1 dim Weierstrass approx theorem, but you do have to know what f(x) is.

Comment: $y = x+n$, where $n$ is a constant.

Comment: What if $x$ and $y$ are independent?